# Copy changes and file names

Tags: client-relations

I searched for copy editing related posts here, and my question is slightly different from what I've read so far. Here's what's happeing:

1. My client is consistently giving me copy with a critical mistake - each copy piece has a "serial number." Example: aa_bb_cc_00_11_22. This number, so far, has been wrong and when I upload the final layout, export a Word Doc, then they tell me it's wrong and I need to do it all over again. I've asked them several times to ensure that the serial number is correct. So far I'm being ignored.
2. The file name should reflect the serial number in these documents. However, depending on when the document gets approved, the serial number will change to reflect the date. The client is trying to make getting the serial number right my responsibility.

How do you handle this? I do value this client, as they provide most of my work. However, if the "aa_bb_cc" part is wrong, I have no way of knowing how to make it right. The date part I could do, but I am concerned about getting this wrong and also having to constantly change it - the client approves but then makes copy changes, or adds stuff, etc. so I don't know when it's really final.
Advice for how to approach the subject? Any experiences of something like this?

Comment: [Related question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/53386/23061)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it the Graphic Designer's job to correct/suggest grammar and punctuation?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70684/is-it-the-graphic-designers-job-to-correct-suggest-grammar-and-punctuation) - see "For technical design assignments (e.g. healthcare), should a graphic designer be expected to look up/suggest corrections for organizations and/or industry terms?"